# php error_log("") below require

Tags: php, error-handling, require, error-logging, error-log

I am trying to print to a log. It will work at the very top of the page but not below a require statement.

This works...

```
<?php 

$log_file = "../../../../errors.log"; 
$error_message = "test! \n";  
error_log($error_message, 3, $log_file);

require '../../../includes/functions.php'; // Utilities functions
```

However, this does not...

```
<?php 

require '../../../includes/functions.php'; // Utilities functions

$log_file = "../../../../errors.log"; 
$error_message = "test! \n";  
error_log($error_message, 3, $log_file);
```

I have tried both require and require_once. Furthermore, I added the following code to the top of the page to override any mistakes that might have been made in the php.ini file:

```
<?php 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require '../../../includes/functions.php'; // Utilities functions

$log_file = "../../../../errors.log"; 
$error_message = "test! \n";  
error_log($error_message, 3, $log_file);
```

I'm new to php and do not understand what is happening here. I also haven't found any similar reports online...

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Post the contents of your functions.php

Comment: Did you redefine `error_log()` in your `functions.php`. Is there an `exit()` somewhere that prevents the rest of the script to be executed ?

Comment: That's a lot of directories to go up from the current directory. You may want to use a path relative to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead. Also, in what way does it not work?

Comment: functions.php path had changed. It's amazing how I will immediately overlook the most simplest possibilities when learning a new language!

Comment: haha. yes, aynber -that's probably why I missed it!